# MySQL: Update with join in subquery

Tags: mysql

I got a table with products and a table with reviews of the products. The products-table has the parent- and child-products. The parent-products should get all reviews from the child-products. I did:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS products;
CREATE TABLE products (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `parent` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `review` decimal(3,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS reviews;
CREATE TABLE reviews (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `product` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `review` decimal(3,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id) 
);

INSERT INTO products SET id=1, parent=null;
INSERT INTO products SET id=2, parent=1;
INSERT INTO products SET id=3, parent=1;

INSERT INTO reviews SET product=2, review=5;
INSERT INTO reviews SET product=3, review=5;
INSERT INTO reviews SET product=3, review=4;

INSERT INTO products SET id=4, parent=null;
INSERT INTO products SET id=5, parent=4;

INSERT INTO reviews SET product=5, review=4;
INSERT INTO reviews SET product=5, review=2;

UPDATE products
SET products.review=
(SELECT SUM(reviews.review)/COUNT(reviews.review) FROM reviews 
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.parent = products.id
)
WHERE products.parent IS NULL;
```

But with that I'm surprised I'm getting an error:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'products.id' in 'on clause'

Any suggestions on how to do it correctly? The idea is that product 1 should get a review of 14/3 = 4.66 and product 4 should get a review of 6/2 = 3.

Comment: I get error 1093, not 1054. What version are you using?

Comment: Thank you for asking an SQL question correctly (with SQL needed to reproduce your example DB) <3 I wish more people followed your example.

Comment: UPDATE products as p1
SET p1.review=
(SELECT SUM(reviews.review)/COUNT(reviews.review) FROM reviews 
where reviews.product = p1.id
)
WHERE p1.parent IS NULL;

Comment: Im using mysql version 5.7.21.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The products is not visible in the subquery. Use following syntax instead:

```
UPDATE products pp
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT pc.parent, SUM(r.review)/COUNT(r.review) as 'rev'
  FROM reviews r
    LEFT JOIN products pc on r.product = pc.id
  GROUP BY pc.parent
) pcc ON pcc.parent = pp.id  
SET pp.review=pcc.rev
WHERE pp.parent IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've declared `p` as an alias for the `products` table, you need to use it throughout the query. So, in your `LEFT JOIN` clause just use `p.parent` instead of `products.parent`.

```
UPDATE products
SET products.review=
(SELECT SUM(reviews.review)/COUNT(reviews.review) FROM reviews 
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.parent = p.id
)
WHERE products.parent IS NULL;
```

Comment: This would not work as it would not connect the products to be updated with the products in the subquery (=all products would get the same review result)

Comment: @slaakso I assumed that the topic starter intentionally simplified his query.

Comment: Mabye a clarification from @Werner. Also the example data could contain another parent with child rows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry, I'm getting "ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'products' for update in FROM clause" on this (MySQL 5.7.21).

Comment: @Werner works just fine for me (MariaDB 10.3). It looks like the MySQL optimizer settings might be an issue for this type of UPDATE..SELECT queries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Answer (score -1):

At its heart, you appear to be looking for this value:

```
SELECT SUM(r.review)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products) n FROM reviews r;
+----------+
| n        |
+----------+
| 4.666667 |
+----------+
```

So, something like...

```
UPDATE products x 
  JOIN (SELECT SUM(r.review)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products) n FROM reviews r) y
   SET x.review = y.n
 WHERE x.review IS NULL;
```

Comment: That would put same calculated for all rows (regardless of it being a parent or a child). As the there is no connection from subquery to main updateadble table (other that the x.review connection, a typo?) all rows will get the same value. Understood that the purpose was to do calculation for each parent based on their child values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, unfortunately this gives a review of 4 to every product in my example.

Comment: This gives a review to every null value only.